# Can I use GCD on an iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, grand-central-dispatch, background-process

I have some code that runs slowly when I test it on an iPhone 4. I am thinking about researching Grand Central Despatch and using a background thread for some tasks. However, I understand that the iPhone 4 is a single core device. Does this mean there will be no benefit on this device to using a background thread?

I couldn't find much in Apple's documentation about different device capabilities in this regard and am new to background processing.

Comment: You haven't described what sort of tasks you want to push to a background queue, but your iPhone 3GS and 4 experience can definitely be enhanced by using Grand Central Dispatch (GCD). For example, I've found that that tasks as simple as loading large images from the `Documents` folder for a tableview or a gallery can prevent the UI from being smooth and graceful as it could be on slower devices, something that is easily remedied with GCD. If you were more specific about what you were thinking of pushing to a background thread, we might be able to offer more meaningful advice.

Comment: I don't know yet. I just wanted to know if it's an option. Seems like it is!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes as long as its running iOS 4 or later. GCD is a good design in that it can be used equally well on single core machines all the way up to 16 Core Mac Pro's. In fact Apple emphasized this when they introduced GCD. If your code is well written it should work equally well on a single core iPhone as well as multicore iOS Devices out there. Theoretically you should see performance improvements on multicore devices over the single core devices.

Comment: Just to be clear - are you saying that a single core iOS4+ device will benefit from GCD, or just that the code will work? I have no performance issues on faster devices, so I don't want to invest the time optimizing if it won't have an impact on a single core device.

Comment: Single Core iOS Devices will still benefit from GCD some, again just not as much as multicore, but still worth it. Programming with GCD is still much easier and simpler than with say programming with pthreads or Cocoas other backgrounding methods, if GCD is available i'd always use it even on single core devices. Plus GCD & blocks open your code up to better design patterns that make for much easier code to write.

Comment: Got it - thanks. I guess I was equating single core with single thread. Glad to have that clarified. To the docs.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends what your code is actually doing. If your code is targeted to calculate only one thing without stopping there is no benefit of using multithreading on one core cpu in terms of performance. If however some of your tasks are waiting for something like network data, waiting on disk operation, sleeping  etc. then your other threads might be using that time to do something useful even on one core cpu. Generally if you are interacting with UI then it is recommended to do time consuming tasks in background so you won't block user interface thus providing better experience for the end user.